# How to label CCA-Plot with row.names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, label, reshape, vegan

I've been trying to solve the following problem which I am sure is an easy one (I am just not able to find a solution). I am using the package vegan and want to perform a cca that shows the actual row names as labels (instead of the default "sit1", "sit2", ...).

I created a dataframe (ls_Treat1) with cast(), showing plot treatments (AB, DB, DL etc.) as row names and species occurences. The dataframe looks as follows:

|  | species 1 | species 2 | species 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| DB | 1 | 6 | 0 |
| DL | 3 | 4 | 2 |

I created the data frame with the following code to set the treatments (AB, DB, DL, ...) as row names:

```
ls_Treat1 <- cast(fungi_ls, Treatment ~ species)
row.names(ls_Treat1)<- ls_Treat1$Treatment
ls_Treat1 <- ls_Treat1[,-1]
```

When I perform a cca with the following code:

```
ca <- cca(ls_Treat1)
plot(ca,display="sites")
```

R puts the default labels "sit1", "sit2", ... into the plot, instead of the actual row names, even though I have performed it this way before and the plots normally showed the right labels. Does this have anything to do with my creating the data frame? I tried to change the treatments (characters) into numbers (integers or factors) but still, the plot won't be labelled with my row names.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you very very much!!

Comment: Hi, I am not able to reproduce your code. Can you add information on all packages you are using? Where does the function "cast" come from? Is fungi_ls a built-in dataset of a package? Or can you also provide code for that, e.g., fungi_ls <- data.frame(colname1 = c("AB","DB"), species1 = c(0,1,3)).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. For cast() I am using the package reshape. fungi_ls ist a data frame that I merged (also with reshape): fungi_ls <- merge(x = fungi_lying, y = fungi_standing, all = T) out of two csv-files:

fungi_lying<-read.csv("2019-10-05_Bestandsexperiment-liegend.csv", 
                      sep = ";", dec = ".", header = T)

fungi_standing<-read.csv("2019-10-05_Bestandsexperiment-stehend.csv", 
                         sep = ";", dec = ".",
                         header = T)

Comment: My guess is that you do not have the row names you assume to have. What do you get from the command rownames(<myfile>)?

Comment: Hi Jari, thanks for your comment, when I perform the command rownames(ls_Treat1), I get the following result: > rownames(ls_Treat1) [1] "AB" "AL" "AR" "AS" "CC" "DB" "DL" "DR" "DS"

Comment: I think there is something fishy in your input data: check what `cast()` gives you – I bet it is not a standard data frame but something messy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `reshape::cast()` does not produce `data.frame` but something else. It claims to be a `data.frame` but it is not. We do matrix algebra in `cca` and therefore we cast input to a matrix which works for standard `data.frame`, but it does not work with the object you supplied as input. In particular, after you remove the first column in `ls_Treat1 <- ls_Treat1[,-1]`, you also remove the attributes that allow preserving names – it would have worked without removing this column (if **reshape** package was still loaded). It seems that upgrading to **reshape2** package and using `reshape2::acast()` can be a solution.

Comment: Hi Jari, thank you very much for your answer and solution! I will try and see what I can make out of it!!

Comment: Hi Jari, I just did what you recommended and it worked! Thanks a lot!